# Sharepoint - GULP SERVE error when trying to create sharepoint clent development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, office365

I followed these steps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) to configure my development environment but it throws me this error that I don't know how to fix

```json
{
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Martina Ojeda\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\prueba\\footer-webpart\\gulpfile.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Martina Ojeda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\node_modules\\gulp-cli\\lib\\shared\\require-or-import.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Martina Ojeda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\node_modules\\gulp-cli\\lib\\versioned\\^3.7.0\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Martina Ojeda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\node_modules\\gulp-cli\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Martina Ojeda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\gulp\\bin\\gulp.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: When do you get the error / what is the problematic step?

Comment: when i run "gulp server"

Comment: what is your node version,npm version?

Comment: version: 4.15.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.15.4  either it is very old or you missed the '1' and it is 14.15.4 .

Anyway modify the version to use LTS 10.x version of Node.js to [fallow the guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#install-nodejs)